# Compact and connected subset of C([0,1])

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness, connectedness

Fix a continuous function $f : [0, 1] × [0, 1] → \mathbb R$. For each $t ∈ [0, 1]$ we define $f_t : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ via $f_t(s) = f(t,s)$. Show that the set of functions  $F =\{f_t : t∈[0,1]\}$
is both a compact and connected subset of $C([0,1])$.

My attempt: I tried to show that $F$ is path-connected in $C([0,1])$, but I realized that the problem does not define a metric over $C([0,1])$. So I cannot use theories of metric space to deal with this problem. (By the way, $C([0,1])=\{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R, f\text{ is continuous}\}$.)

Comment: The usual metric on $C([0,1])$ is the uniform metric: $d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$.  That's presumably what the problem is assuming.  You absolutely can and should use what you know about metric spaces for this problem.

Comment: By the way, consider using [proper MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164); your questions will be easier to read and people will be more willing to spend time on them.

Comment: @NateEldredge . And, I suppose, the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem too.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I thought so too at first, but in this problem I think you can give an elementary proof that doesn't need it.  The key will be to show that $t \mapsto f_t$ is continuous, i.e. if $t_n \to t$ then $f_{t_n} \to f_t$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Yeah, that is what I did. Since f continuous and the domain is compact, any d(f(a,b), f(c,d)) is in R. Then apply the definition of continuity when fixing s. Then I got the answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge . Yes. Very simple, since f is uniformly continuous.